# Export as .fbx with uv-mapped texture

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I want to export my blender model as a .fbx file. 
The model (eg. a cube) has a material and a uv-mapped texture attatched to it.

I can see the reference to the texture (.png file located seperately from the .fbx) in the .fbx file when I open the file in a text editor:

```
[...]Material: "Material::Material_002__uvlayout_png_png", "" {
    Version: 102
    ShadingModel: "lambert"
    MultiLayer: 0
    Properties60:  {
        Property: "ShadingModel", "KString", "", "Lambert"
        Property: "MultiLayer", "bool", "",0
        Property: "EmissiveColor", "ColorRGB", "",0.8000,0.8000,0.8000
        Property: "EmissiveFactor", "double", "",0.0000
        Property: "AmbientColor", "ColorRGB", "",1.0000,1.0000,1.0000
        Property: "AmbientFactor", "double", "",1.0000
        Property: "DiffuseColor", "ColorRGB", "",0.8000,0.8000,0.8000
        Property: "DiffuseFactor", "double", "",0.8000
        Property: "Bump", "Vector3D", "",0,0,0
        Property: "TransparentColor", "ColorRGB", "",1,1,1
        Property: "TransparencyFactor", "double", "",0.0000
        Property: "SpecularColor", "ColorRGB", "",1.0000,1.0000,1.0000
        Property: "SpecularFactor", "double", "",0.5000
        Property: "ShininessExponent", "double", "",12.3
        Property: "ReflectionColor", "ColorRGB", "",0,0,0
        Property: "ReflectionFactor", "double", "",1
        Property: "Emissive", "ColorRGB", "",0,0,0
        Property: "Ambient", "ColorRGB", "",1.0,1.0,1.0
        Property: "Diffuse", "ColorRGB", "",0.8,0.8,0.8
        Property: "Specular", "ColorRGB", "",1.0,1.0,1.0
        Property: "Shininess", "double", "",12.3
        Property: "Opacity", "double", "",1.0
        Property: "Reflectivity", "double", "",0
    }
}
Video: "Video::uvlayout_png_png", "Clip" {
    Type: "Clip"
    Properties60:  {
        Property: "FrameRate", "double", "",0
        Property: "LastFrame", "int", "",0
        Property: "Width", "int", "",0
        Property: "Height", "int", "",0
        Property: "Path", "charptr", "", "uvlayout.png.png"
        Property: "StartFrame", "int", "",0
        Property: "StopFrame", "int", "",0
        Property: "PlaySpeed", "double", "",1
        Property: "Offset", "KTime", "",0
        Property: "InterlaceMode", "enum", "",0
        Property: "FreeRunning", "bool", "",0
        Property: "Loop", "bool", "",0
        Property: "AccessMode", "enum", "",0
    }
    UseMipMap: 0
    Filename: "uvlayout.png.png"
    RelativeFilename: "uvlayout.png.png"
}
Texture: "Texture::uvlayout_png_png", "TextureVideoClip" {
    Type: "TextureVideoClip"
    Version: 202
    TextureName: "Texture::uvlayout_png_png"
    Properties60:  {
        Property: "Translation", "Vector", "A+",0,0,0
        Property: "Rotation", "Vector", "A+",0,0,0
        Property: "Scaling", "Vector", "A+",1,1,1
        Property: "Texture alpha", "Number", "A+",0
        Property: "TextureTypeUse", "enum", "",0
        Property: "CurrentTextureBlendMode", "enum", "",1
        Property: "UseMaterial", "bool", "",0
        Property: "UseMipMap", "bool", "",0
        Property: "CurrentMappingType", "enum", "",0
        Property: "UVSwap", "bool", "",0
        Property: "WrapModeU", "enum", "",0
        Property: "WrapModeV", "enum", "",0
        Property: "TextureRotationPivot", "Vector3D", "",0,0,0
        Property: "TextureScalingPivot", "Vector3D", "",0,0,0
        Property: "VideoProperty", "object", ""
    }
    Media: "Video::uvlayout_png_png"
    FileName: "uvlayout.png.png"
    RelativeFilename: "uvlayout.png.png"
    ModelUVTranslation: 0,0
    ModelUVScaling: 1,1
    Texture_Alpha_Source: "None"
    Cropping: 0,0,0,0
}
[...]
```

The Model needs the texture reference when I want to display it out of blender and thats just fine. It also gets displayed in the right way.

The problem is that I followed a tutorial and even with looking the tutorial about uv-mapping again, following each step, i cannot reproduce the same kind of cube.

In blender, the uv-mapped texture gets displayed right but as I export it to .fbx, the whole texture reference is missing in the file:

```
[...]Material: "Material::TexturedMaterial_cubetexture", "" {
    Version: 102
    ShadingModel: "lambert"
    MultiLayer: 0
    Properties60:  {
        Property: "ShadingModel", "KString", "", "Lambert"
        Property: "MultiLayer", "bool", "",0
        Property: "EmissiveColor", "ColorRGB", "",0.8000,0.8000,0.8000
        Property: "EmissiveFactor", "double", "",0.0000
        Property: "AmbientColor", "ColorRGB", "",1.0000,1.0000,1.0000
        Property: "AmbientFactor", "double", "",1.0000
        Property: "DiffuseColor", "ColorRGB", "",0.8000,0.8000,0.8000
        Property: "DiffuseFactor", "double", "",0.8000
        Property: "Bump", "Vector3D", "",0,0,0
        Property: "TransparentColor", "ColorRGB", "",1,1,1
        Property: "TransparencyFactor", "double", "",0.0000
        Property: "SpecularColor", "ColorRGB", "",1.0000,1.0000,1.0000
        Property: "SpecularFactor", "double", "",0.5000
        Property: "ShininessExponent", "double", "",12.3
        Property: "ReflectionColor", "ColorRGB", "",0,0,0
        Property: "ReflectionFactor", "double", "",1
        Property: "Emissive", "ColorRGB", "",0,0,0
        Property: "Ambient", "ColorRGB", "",1.0,1.0,1.0
        Property: "Diffuse", "ColorRGB", "",0.8,0.8,0.8
        Property: "Specular", "ColorRGB", "",1.0,1.0,1.0
        Property: "Shininess", "double", "",12.3
        Property: "Opacity", "double", "",1.0
        Property: "Reflectivity", "double", "",0
    }
}
Pose: "Pose::BIND_POSES", "BindPose" {
    Type: "BindPose"
    Version: 100
    Properties60:  {
    }
    NbPoseNodes: 1
    PoseNode:  {
        Node: "Model::Cube"
        Matrix: 0.000000075497901,0.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,-0.000000075497901,0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,1.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000,1.000000000000000
    }
}
GlobalSettings:  {
    Version: 1000
    Properties60:  {
        Property: "UpAxis", "int", "",1
        Property: "UpAxisSign", "int", "",1
        Property: "FrontAxis", "int", "",2
        Property: "FrontAxisSign", "int", "",1
        Property: "CoordAxis", "int", "",0
        Property: "CoordAxisSign", "int", "",1
        Property: "UnitScaleFactor", "double", "",1
    }
}
[...]
```

The UV coordinates are exported correcty.. only the texture reference is missing.

Comment: Are you using "Cycles Render"? I had trouble getting textures to work with it. Worked fine with "Blender Render" though. Not really a solution, but maybe this helps. 

Also, you will likely want to use a relative path for your texture image: File->External Data->Make All Paths Relative

Comment: This question is somehow really old and I found a workaround. My Blender version was somehow messed up and after using relative paths and clicking on different buttons to map the texture fixed it. I remember that I had to leave the UV-Map windows selected when exporting the models.. but i guessed this is fixed with later versions of blender because the re-downloaded factory version worked out of the box. Still thanks for your reply!